# Powershell passing object as part of .replace

Tags: powershell, replace, directoryservices

I have a script that I am writing to return all of the users and their OUs that have mailboxes.  My only problems is that distinguishedname returns

CN=user,OU=...

I just want OU=...

It is my last line that is not formatted correctly

```
$($objItem.distinguishedname.replace('CN=$($objItem.name),',''))"
```

In this piece of the last line I want to replace where I find the phrase CN= data returned from the object with a blank.

So if $(objItem.name) contained Bob

I would want this to perform the following replace

```
$objItem.distinguishedname.replace('CN=Bob,','')
```

How would I format this?  I have also tried the following

```
$($objItem.distinguishedname[0].replace('CN=$($objItem.name),',''))
```

which doesn't return an error but replaces nothing.  If I change it to

```
$($objItem.distinguishedname[0].replace('CN=',''))
```

it removes all the CN= in front.  I feel close.

Below is the full script.

```
$strFilter = "(&(&(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(HomeMDB=*)))))"

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

$colProplist = "name","distinguishedname", "samaccountname"

foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
{
    $objItem = $objResult.Properties; 
    write-Host "$($objItem.samaccountname) $($objItem.name)$($objItem.distinguishedname.replace('CN=$($objItem.name),',''))"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't expand variables inside of single quotes:

```
'CN=$($objItem.name),'
```

Perhaps you want this:

```
"... $($objItem.distinguishedname[0].replace(`"CN=$($objItem.name),`",''))"
```

Here's an example:

```
$objItem = [pscustomobject]@{DistinguishedName='CN=Bob,OU=blah','';Name='Bob'}
"Blah ... $($objItem.distinguishedname[0].replace(`"CN=$($objItem.name),`",''))"
```

Outputs:

```
Blah ... OU=blah
```

Comment: No luck.  Didn't like ending with '", and it was treating it as an object not the text.  I even tried `$($objItem.distinguishedname[0].replace('"CN=$($objItem.name),"',''))` and that didn't work either.

Comment: *Both* of the inner double quotes have to be escaped.  Look at my version more closely.  :-)  BTW I updated the example to show it inside the context of another double quoted string.

Comment: Note the use of the backtick character (a.k.a. "grave accent") for escaping in Keith's code, it's NOT a single quote mark.  It's the one above the tab key on a standard US Keyboard.

Comment: Since my edit will not be approved of changing `distinguishedname` to `distinguishedname[0]` I cannot accept your answer @KeithHill until you edit it as it will not work with my code provided above although your example does work fine stand alone.

Comment: @KeithHill I accepted again, but you did not have to change your example.  It was right without the 0 because in your example distinguishedname contains a string.  In my case distinguishedname is another object.  It just happens it has only one value in the object at index 0 which is a string.  I would leave "Perhaps you want this" section the way it is and change your "Here's an example" back to not have the 0.  Just want the next guy who runs across this to get working code :)

Comment: The last example works.  If you look at the pscustomobject's distinguishedname property, you will see that it is an array with two elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$($objItem.distinguishedname[0] -creplace 'CN=[^,]+,')
```

Is this work for you:

```
....
...
$objItem = $objResult.Properties;
$del = 'CN={0},' -f $($objItem.name)
.......$($objItem.distinguishedname[0] -creplace "$del")
```

Comment: I need it to be on the fly.  If the users name is Steve I need it to replace Steve with a blank as well.

Comment: You can use -replace operator instead like this: `$yourobject -creplace 'CN=[^,]+,'`

Comment: I think `$yourobject -creplace 'CN=[^,]+,'` does solve my problem because I want to replace everything starting with CN up to and including the first comma, but what if I really only wanted to replace something from another object?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than replace I'll offer Split as an alternative. This will split on a comma and return a 2 item array, the first item being CN=Name and the second item is OU=Path. Then I pipe to Select and skip the first one, returning only the OU= portion of the string.

```
$objItem.distinguishedname -split ",",2|select -skip 1
```

Then you could use it something like:

```
Write-Host ("{0} {1}{2}" -f $objItem.samaccountname, $objItem.name, ($objItem.distinguishedname -split ",",2|select -skip 1))
```

That will give an output like you have in your example of their SAMAccountName, followed by a space, followed by their Name, and immediately following that will be their DistinguishedName with the CN=Name portion of it removed.